# Use to host email for a domain name that wasn't our primary domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, email, exchange-2007, internal-dns

Exchange 2007 on an Server 2003 active directory.  My primary domain (MyMainDomain.com) controller also hosts dns and dhcp.

I have a secondary domain name (MySecondDomain.net) that my Exchange Server allows emails from.  It wasn't a physical domain, just accepted by exchange and setup as the Active Directory user's main smtp and outgoing address.  Its MX records point to MyMainDomain.com's public exchange address.

I've taken MySecondDomain.net and move the mail boxes to a hosted exchange 2010 environment.  MX records now point to this new exchange system and when I send and email OUTSIDE the MyMainDomain.com environment (say gmail) it works and sends to the hosted exchange setup for MySecondDomain.net.

however when I send an email from a user on MyMainDomain.com, it goes to the old exchange 2007 server I am hosting internally.  I have removed MySecondDomain.net from the allowed domains, removed the DNS zone for MySecondDomain.net, and cleared DNS cache.  I was convinced it was my internal dns server but I've cleared the DNS cache.

Is there something I'm missing somewhere in exchange 2007?  Or is it my domain controller/dns?  Sorry if this is confusing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove it from your email address policy. After you do that make sure that the email address has been removed from all mail enabled objects (users, groups, etc.).

Comment: Just did that.  Still nothing.  I wonder if it is something with the GAL?

Comment: When I double click an underlined email address in my TO bar, and go to the email addresses tab, it still shows the smtp=user@MySecondDomain.net along with smtp=user@MyMainDomain.com

Comment: It has to be the global address list, because when I see them there and choose them it sends to the old mailbox.

Comment: You're mixing things up. Sending to the second domain's email address and sending to the user's mailbox are two different things. If you removed the second domain from Exchange and none of the users have that email address then sending to that email address will send the email to the external host. That does not mean that the users don't have mailboxes, don't show up in the GAL, and won't receive internally generated emails, because they do and they will. In addition, you need to manually delete the old email address entries form your Outlook nickname cache.